# How can I refine my R script to return the final output in a single script?

Tags: r

I have the task of graphing volatility of a time series with about 500 000 elements over 22 days. I'd like to graph the volatility in different scales, i.e., day, 3-hours, 1-hour, 20-minute, 1-minute and so on, but I'd also like these to overlap. For example, for the 1-hour scale I'd like it to output the volatility of 10am-11am, 10.30-11.30, 11-12,etc.

I could do it all outside of a loop, but that would take a lot longer. I know it can be done more efficiently, but I find `data.frames` inside lists inside more lists very difficult to understand at the moment.

Here is my reproducible example, I hope it's sufficient

```
x<-rnorm(6000,0,1)
price<- cumsum(x)   # this represents stock tick data

day1<-sort( runif(3000,0,6) , decreasing = FALSE)+10 #generate random ordered time stamps between 10:00-16:00 for each trade event
day2<-sort( runif(1000,0,6) , decreasing = FALSE)+10 # only 1000 trade events on this day, hence 1000 timestamps
day3<-sort( runif(2000,0,6) , decreasing = FALSE)+10 # (my actual real world data spans 28 days)

time<-c(day1,day2,day3)

date<-c( rep(20110925L,3000) , rep(20110930L,1000) , rep(20110931L, 2000) ) # the 3 dates are 25/9/2011, 30/9/2011, 31/9/2011

mydata<-data.frame( cbind(date,time,price) )

# I would like to create one single loop to graph the volitilty over different periods using 1 minute, 20 min, 1 hour and whole day blocks. 
# I would also like to implement it so that it examines the inbetween block-eg. for 20 minute blocks: it looks at 10:00-10:20, 10:10-10:30,10:20-10:40, etc.
# finally i would like to graph these, but I am really new to R so i'm finding it very difficult. I would love some guidance, tips and tricks
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about how to use R without a reproducible example.

Comment: i will be able to add a reproducible examine in about 2 hours. can also repost then

Comment: Please don't repost. Just add a reproducible example & we can migrate this to where you can get some help.

Comment: I have added a reproducible example. hope it's ok